Error accessing media devices: DOMException
brand new to react and am trying to get access of camera and mic but i ran to this error:
Error accessing media devices: DOMException { line: 1, column: 161443, sourceURL: "https://sample.com/user/static/js/838.d273e7b8.chunk.js" }

my code works perfect on desktop browsers but it doesn't work on any mobile devices ( i have an iphone and tried it with brave, chrome, safari and firefox )
here is my full code
    useEffect(() => {
        const setupMedia = async () => {
            try {
                const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video: { facingMode: 'user' },
                    audio: true,
                })

                if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm')) {
                    console.warn('video/webm is not supported')
                    return
                }

                if (videoLiveRef.current) {
                    videoLiveRef.current.srcObject = mediaStream
                }

                mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, {
                    mimeType: 'video/webm',
                })

                mediaRecorderRef.current.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
                    const blob = new Blob([event.data], { type: 'video/webm' })
                    videoRecordedRef.current.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                    setAuthData({ type: 4, payload: { file: blob } })
                    
                })
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error accessing media devices:', error)
                setToast({
                    isError: true,
                    show: true,
                    message:
                        'Unable to access camera and microphone. Please check your device settings and browser permissions.',
                })
            }
        }

        setupMedia()
    }, [setAuthData, setToast, lang])


Unfortunately there is only one browser engine allowed on iOS. Apple doesn't allow any other. Even though you can install browsers with different names they all have to use WebKit on the inside. WebKit is the browser engine of Safari.
WebKit does not support recording anything as 'video/webm'. Therefore the error must get triggered before you check for that.
const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: { facingMode: 'user' },
    audio: true,
})

It's possible that the browsers don't have permission to use either the camera or the microphone and therefore the call to getUserMedia() gets rejected right away.
